# How to tell if user has auto-update selected in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I want to detect if a user has auto-update enabled for my app in the Android Market. For users that do not have this enabled I want to show a popup notifying of critical App updates. I would like to know of any API (Intent?) that I can use to query if auto-update is selected for my App in the Market.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. As far as I know the update function is a part of Android Market and has nothing to do with you/any other app.

Comment: Your best bet would be to have the application itself check if a newer version of itself is out and it can notify the user. You'd have to setup a webserver or something for it to communicate with. Not the market

Comment: @Spidy I am already doing this; the reason for this question is that I do not want to notify users that have turned on auto-update - don't want to waste their time.

Comment: If they have auto-update turned on, then they will always have the most up-to-date version and never get the message. Unless you change permissions on the app in which auto-update doesn't run.